# Data Analysis and Probability

Tags: data-analysis

Two dice with a difference ... They appear identical, but one die is fair and the other is loaded so that the probability of throwing a 6 is 0.25.
Bev picks a die at random and throws it, and it shows a 6. Find the probability that she picked the biased die.

(Hint: Let A be the event 'the die chosen is the biased one' and B be 'a die chosen at random shows a 6 when it is thrown'. Find  $P(A|B).)

I know $P(A) = 1/2$,
       $P(B) = (1/2 \times 0.25) + (1/2 \times 1/6) = 5/24$

Don't know what $P(A|B)$ is and what to do do next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic formula that *defines* the conditional probability $\Pr(A|B)$ is
$$\Pr(A|B)=\frac{\Pr(A\cap B)}{\Pr(B)}.\tag{1}$$
You already computed $\Pr(B)$.

As to $\Pr(A\cap B)$, the probability that you picked the biased die and threw a $6$, you also already computed it as part of the calculation of $\Pr(B)$: It is $(1/2)(0.25)$.

So all that is left to do is the division asked for by Formula (1).

Comment: Ahhh thank you, Andre! I was twisting myself up just thinking about this thing. It's really simple with your explanation. Thaaaank yaaaaaaaaw!

Comment: You are welcome. Formula (1) is very basic, and comes up explicitly or implicitly whenever one is dealing with conditional probabilities.

Comment: Final answer without rounding:p(A/B) = 0.125/0.20833333 = 0.6000000096000002

Comment: The **exact** answer is $\frac{3}{5}$, which is $0.6$. The extra digits you got come from truncating. Your calculator or calculator program would probably have come up with $0.6$ if you did not rekey partial computations, and used instead the "memory" feature.